# PHP - Regular expression - number matching before specific character

Tags: php, regex

I have this kind of string:

> 1234567890(number without specific number of character)-(minus symbol serves as divider)text

How can I see and extract number before **-** symbol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regex like this:

```
preg_match('/^(\d+)/', '123-something', $match);
```

This will capture all decimal digits from the start of the string until the first non-decimal digit, and the result will be in the `$match` variable.

```
if (preg_match('/^(\d+)/', $string, $match)) {
    $number = $match[1];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `preg_split()`

```
$bla=preg_split('#(?<=\d)-(?=[a-z])#i', "1234567890-asdlkj");
echo $bla[0];
```

gives `1234567890`

If you want the text field,you can use

```
echo $bla[1];
```

gives `asdlkj`